# Is it possible to adapt Keccak to use 60-bit native words, without having to emulate U64?

Tags: hash, keccak

Assume an architecture with fast 60-bit native words (a close example would be Ocaml, which has unboxed 63-bit numbers, and only boxed 64-bit numbers). We're looking for the fastest hash function in that architecture. Keccak is great, but our best bet, so far, is to port it from implementations that use 32-bit numbers, such as JavaScript. That would be sub-optimal. I wonder if it is possible to modify Keccak to use 60-bit words in its internal states. It would be a different function, but that is fine. Is there any guideline on how to do so safely?

Comment: Actually, it is known that the Keccak operation modified to have $z=60$ (but otherwise unchanged) is not invertible, that is, not a permutation; I don't know what affect that would have on the security (or how much 'entropy' the nonpermutation would lose)...